# AngularJs, reducing logic in html templates

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have an html template where the conditionals in the ng-ifs and ng-shows are getting a bit too complex to belong in the UI.  For example, this is to determine if payment controls should be displayed:

```
<div ng-show="ticket.status == 0 && 
  ((ticket.orgTicketId === '' && ticketControl.balance > 0 ) || 
  (ticket.orgTicketId !== '' && ticketControl.balance < 0))">
```

I would like to simplify this to something like this:

```
<div ng-show="ticket.paymentsAllowed">
```

I would prefer to not move the logic into the controller, since I am trying to keep it as clean as possible as well.

In C#, which is where I come from, I would just add a property to the Ticket class called PaymentsAllowed and move the logic there.

**I am fairly new to Javascript and AngularJs and I am looking for advice on how to accomplish something similar here, so that I can clean up the html templates and make them more legible.**

The Angular app gets JSON from a WebAPI backend, which I simply assign to the $scope; this is all working well.  Here is a simplified example of retrieving a ticket.

The ticketService reads the ticket view model from the backend:

```
function getTicket(ticketId) {
    var deferred = common.$q.defer();

    common.$http.get("api/tickets/" + ticketId)
      .success(function (ticket) {
         deferred.resolve(ticket);
      }));

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

The controller uses the ticketService to retrieve ticket and assign to $scope.ticket:

```
ticketService.getTicket(123).then(
  function (ticket) {
    $scope.ticket = ticket;
  });
```

**I like the simplicity of just retrieving view models in the form of JSON data from the WebAPI and binding it straight to the proper scope, but what is a simple, clean way to add some simple business logic to these javascript objects?**

Comment: thats the reason angularjs has services/factories

Comment: @harish That would still require me to add a method to the controller, which in turn would call the service / factory.  I am looking for something cleaner, if there is such a thing.

Comment: How is adding a function to the controller unclean? `ng-show="paymentsAllowed()"` would solve all of your problems

Comment: Create method in factory, and put that factory on scope, more thou can call factory method directly from html

Comment: I already have a number of such controller "stubs", which only acts as relays to a service.  I was just hoping that there was a cleaner way - these "stubs" really fill no other function than relaying to a service.  I was thinking that perhaps prototypal inheritance or similar could be used here, creating a Ticket "class" (but I do not understand it well enough to see how, without adding more complexity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to "revive" the data retrived as json with behaviour to complement the data, for example like so:

```
function Ticket(data) {
  angular.copy(data, this); // copy json data into this, which will have our prototype.
}  
Ticket.prototype.paymentsAllowed = function (ticketControl) {
  return this.status == 0 && 
    ((this.orgTicketId === '' && ticketControl.balance > 0 ) || 
    (this.orgTicketId !== '' && ticketControl.balance < 0))
}

function getTicket(ticketId) {
  var deferred = common.$q.defer();

  common.$http.get("api/tickets/" + ticketId)
    .success(function (ticket) {
       deferred.resolve(new Ticket(ticket));
    }));

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

The ticket in the scope will then by prototype inheritance have the method paymentsAllowed(..), which can be accessed in the template like so

```
<div ng-show="ticket.paymentsAllowed(ticketControl)">
```

Comment: I like this approach, The paymentsAllowed method / flag is mure more appropriate in the service, or even on the server/db side than in the controller/view.

Answer (score 1):

Without adding functions to your controller, you could use a Directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('ticket-payment', [function() {
    return {
        template: '<div class="ticket-payment">payment options</div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var status = attrs.status;
            var orgTicketId = attrs.orgTicketId;
            var balance = attrs.balance;

            if (status == 0 &&
              ((orgTicketId === '' && balance > 0) ||
              (orgTicketId !== '' && balance < 0))) {
                element.hide();
            }
        }
    };
});
```

At least your HTML would look a little cleaner

```
<div ticket-payment
     status="{{ticket.status}}"
     orgTicketId="{{ticket.orgTicketId}}"
     balance="{{ticketControl.balance}}">
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it will make the html cleaner and I like to encapsulate stuff in custom directives where appropriate, but a custom directive for this scenario seems a bit overkill and adds quite a bit of extra complexity for something fairly simple (especially since I the example I provided is just one of many similar cases, so it would take lots of directives).

Comment: I agree. Directives for this scenario would be a little overkill.

Answer (score 0):

```js
ticketService.getTicket(123).then(
  function (ticket) {
    $scope.ticket = ticket;
    $scope.ticket.paymentsAllowed=IsPaymentsAllowed(ticket);
  });
//Define IsPaymentsAllowed function to return a bool value based on your condition
```

Comment: This does not work, since the IsPaymentsAllowed method is only called that one time, so paymentsAllowed does not reflect subsequent changes to the ticket.

Comment: hmm, do you mean that the condition variables may be changed by the user thus should be reflected on the show condition ? did you mean so ?

Comment: Sure.  It is an order entry / ticket entry app, and the variables for determining whether or not to show something change constantly.  The logic in question needs to always operate on the current state.

Answer (score 0):

You can always define your logic on the controller and then call it from your template, this way you have a live updatable status:

On your template:

```
<div ng-show="isPaymentAllowed(ticket)">
    <!-- your html stuff -->
</div>
```

On your controller:

```
$scope.isPaymentAllowed = function(ticketToCheck){
    // Put your logic here, returning true or false
    return true
}
```

Angular will automatically recheck your status when any of your involved variables change.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, I know - this is better than having the logic in the HTML, but like I said in my question I would prefer to not move the the logic into the controller if it is possible (in a clean way).

Answer (score 0):

You could use angular's `$resource` provider, combined with inheritance.

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('Tickets', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    var Tickets = $resource('api/tickets/:ticketId');

    angular.extend(Tickets.prototype, {
        paymentsAllowed: function() {
            return this.status == 0 && 
                   ((this.orgTicketId === '' && this.balance > 0 ) || 
                   (this.orgTicketId !== '' && this.balance < 0));
        }
    }

    return Tickets;
});
```

Now, when you fetch a ticket, you would do it through the `Tickets` factory

```
$scope.ticket = Tickets.get({ ticketId: 123 });
```

And, in your view:

```
<div ng-show="ticket.paymentsAllowed()"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a $watch-er

```
// update paymentAllowed when ticket changes
$scope.$watch('ticket', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    $scope.paymentAllowed = (newValue.status == 0 &&
                            ((newValue.orgTicketId === '' && newValue.balance > 0) ||
                            (newValue.orgTicketId !== '' && newValue.balance < 0)));
}, true);
```

The final `true` argument tells `$watch` that `ticket` is an object, and should perform a deep comparison before triggering.

Then you could simply use the `paymentAllowed` property

```
<div ng-show="paymentAllowed"></div>
```

Comment: I do not see how this would be any better than having a $scope.paymentAllowed function that containsn the logic.  Based on the answers / suggestions received so far, it appears that having the logic in the controller (or a "stub" in the controller which calls a service) is as clean as it is going to get...

Comment: It is essentially equivalent to adding a function to the controller. You're looking for something that extends the ticket object itself?

Comment: I guess.  I was hoping for an easy, clean way to add simple logic to a javascript object that operates on the current data of that object.  For a ticket or order object, this would allow me to add properties or functions like paymentAllowed, hasReturns, etc.  But it cannot interfere with the simplicity of assigning json view models from the WebAPI backend directly to the scope - I don't want to wind up just moving complexity from one part to another....  But again, I am influenced by my C# background, and this might not be feasible in javascript.